# In Ember 2 with components how can I avoid using an observer when I want to create records alongside other record creation

Tags: ember.js

As an example:

Lets say I have a model, Food.js with:

```
name: DS.attr('string'),
groupName: DS.attr('string'),
isMeat: DS.attr('boolean'),
kitchen: DS.belongsTo('kitchen', {async: true})
```

And I also have a model, Fridge.js with:

```
name: DS.attr('string'),
groupName: DS.attr('string'),
kitchen: DS.belongsTo('kitchen', {async: true})
```

These are collected together in a Kitchen Model:

```
name: DS.attr('string'),
foods: DS.hasMany('food', {async: true}),
fridges: DS.hasMany('fridge', {async: true})
```

I have a main component that manages creation of a kitchen. In a child component a user can create new foods in the store, and save to database. The component also allows users to edit foods already in the kitchen.

What I want to happen is that Fridge records are automatically created or deleted depending on how many fridges are required. Currently I would do this in the kitchen management component with an observer like this:

```
foodToFridgeMapper: function() {
  Ember.run.once(this, function() {
    // Loop through all the foods, populate requiredFridges based on isMeat and groupNames
    let requiredFridges = ...;

    // Compare required fridges to existing fridges
    // Call deleteRecord on any no longer required
    // Create record for any that don't exist and are required
    ...
  }
}.observes('kitchen.foods.[]', 'kitchen.foods.@each.isMeat', 'kitchen.foods.@each.groupName')
```

I hate observers. How can I achieve logic that creates and deletes records alongside another array, but avoiding them?

---

Note this question is similar to [Ember — observe for creation/deletion of records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982638/ember-observe-for-creation-deletion-of-records) but different in that the focus here is how to move everything outside of an observer and in a component situation, not controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recipe: find the lowest common ancestor of

1. the component where the food creation event is captured
2. the component where the fridges need to be created

Then, send an action up to that component and handle the fridge creation/deletion there.

This article from Sam Selikoff is really great and it helped me to build better UI's: http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/lowest-common-ancestor/

Comment: And if we use ember wormhole as you suggested then we can bring them much closer together and then use DDAU. In the meantime creation of fridges can actually be done in the component that creates food, as it can also see the current fridges, so the LCA is itself in a weird way.