# Ember database new record event and observer

Tags: ember.js, firebase, ember-data, firebase-realtime-database, emberfire

My web app is built using Ember.JS and Firebase for storing data. It also serves as a backend for a mobile app. Users can use mobile app to send a 'help-request' - the app manipulates directly with the Firebase records. When the change is made admin of the web app can see the notification on the screen. That works fine. Now I want to add a sound to this notification.

My general idea to solve it to add an observer that will be triggered when a new record of help-request type is added to the database.

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982638/ember-observe-for-creation-deletion-of-records) sort of explaining how to do it but it's using deprecated methods like ArrayControler.

I added a simple observer to help-request model that is triggered when property/ies of the record are modified. That works fine but seems to be a hack rather than a real solution.

So the big question is: 
1. Is there any callback, or event, or notification that I can subscribe to check if a new record is created in the Firebase? If so how would I subscribe to it?

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    device: DS.attr('string'),
    userName: DS.attr('string'),
    locationName: DS.attr('string'),
    type: DS.attr('string'),
    fullNameChanged: function() {

      // deal with the change
      console.log("FULL NAME");
    }.observes('device').on('init')
});
```

My Second approach: 
Did Create - never called when the changes are made to Firebase directly.

```
didCreate:function(){
  console.log("Created");
  var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
    url: 'assets/beep22.mp3'
  });
  mySound.play();
},
```

Did update - called but the property is not persisted

```
didUpdate:function(){
  console.log("Updated");
  console.log((this.get('shouldPlay')));
}
```

Did Load - seemed to be the best approach but the changes are not persisted :(

```
didLoad:function(){
  console.log("Did load");
   if(this.get('shouldPlay')){
     var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
     url: 'assets/beep22.mp3'
  });
  mySound.play();
  this.set('shouldPlay','false');
  this.save().then(() => {
      console.log("saved");
  },(error)=>{
      console.log(error);
  });

}
```

}

Update:

```
 this.set('shouldPlay','false');
```

should be

```
this.set('shouldPlay',false);
```

This is how it finally worked.

Comment: Did you check hooks on ember model like [didLoad](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html)?

Comment: Not until you told me too. It works! Can you submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When firebase adds new record into the store it's actually loaded not created. So you can use  `didLoad` hook on [ember model](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#event_didLoad).
I would also suggest creating service to play sounds. It will make things easier down the road.

```
// models/help-request.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';
const {inject: {service}} = Ember;

export default DS.Model.extend({
  soundPlayer: service(),

  didLoad() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.get('soundPlayer').newHelpRequest(this);
  },
});

// services/sound-player.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    const beep = soundManager.createSound({
      url: 'assets/beep22.mp3',
    });
    this.set('beep', beep);
  }

  play(sound) {
    this.get(sound).play();
  },

  newHelpRequest(helpRequest) {
    if (!helpRequest.get('_didNotify')) {
      helpRequest.set('_didNotify', true);
      this.play('beep');
    }
  },
});
```